# Can "morally" mean "approximately"?

Tags: word-usage

I asked [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37664595/402884) about these uses of "moral":

- [*Fast and Loose Reasoning is Morally Correct*](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/publications/danielsson-et-al-popl2006.html)
- Purescript [`Aff`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff/0.16.1/docs/Control.Monad.Aff#t:Aff) documentation:

  > This is moral equivalent of `ErrorT (ContT Unit (Eff e)) a`.

The responses I've gotten are that "morally" is used to qualify a statement in the same way one would use "basically", as a hedge for a statement that is not perfectly true, but true enough for practical purposes.

Is this word usage normal outside of programming/math?

Comment: Yes. It's a metaphorical usage. But it doesn't 'mean' approximately, it means morally with the implication that it is not exactly equivalent, but is equivalent as far as morals go.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of *[moral](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/moral_1)* that applies in *moral equivalent* is

> based on what you believe is right instead of what the law or rules
>   say is right

So a *moral equivalent* is something that may not be strictly true, but is something that is believed to be true, or, as you say, is perhaps close enough to the truth for practical purposes.

I would disagree that it's like saying *[basically](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/basically)*, which Macmillan defines as

> used for saying that you are talking about the most important aspects
>   of something and not mentioning the specific details